# How to set one white space as width as one character in wordpress?

Tags: content-width, pre

My wp theme is twentyfifteen ,font in style.css is inherit,the font in firefox is noto mono.
I found that one white space is as width as one character in wordpress development--this forum,two white spaces is as width as one character in my wordpress.

[image]

How to set one white space as width as one character in wordpress?

Comment: I see one white space having one character width between your shared x and y characters. Why do you think they are two?

Comment: dear vinod dalvi,it is two white spaces inputted

Comment: Then could you please share the page URL where it is displaying so that i can troubleshoot it?

Comment: It is a font-family problem,when to change font into `Courier 10 Pitch`,one white space is as width as one character now.

Comment: Sounds like you either need a monospace font - Courier is one, where like a typewriter, all characters including spaces are the same width - or, if the issue is that you're trying to get two spaces to show in a row and only one is showing, the only way to get it to show is to use &nbsp; instead of the space character. Browsers by default collapse 2 spaces down to 1.